Trying to enable the ability to install a specific application for a Windows game from Steam
I am playing a game from Steam that requires a separate service application to run the way I need it to, but it won't seem to allow the install on my Ubuntu 22.04 OS. Although I see a console flash a few times on my screen for a few moments, the standard password prompt for the Linux OS when you're trying to install something new does not pop-up, so I can accept the installation. I'm assuming this is because the application is not a Linux app.
What I want to know is if there is a way that can give a specific application the ability to bypass the need for the password prompt before installation?

This is probably not the problem; Wine runs as user, and all installation is done in your home directory, unlike system software. There's some other reason; your console output may tell you what. Not all apps works with wine, and some may require additional configuration.
